# I know this is a very basic question but I am new to statistics

Tags: r, anova

How would you approach analysis of 6 groups representing a range of values, increasing in value against a continuous variable (number) ?

I am learning to use R right now. Would I have to use ANOVA?
Please let me know thank you

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. How you choose to model your data depends on what assumptions you are willing to make and what type of conclusions you want to draw. This is a statistical questions and the site for statistical questions is [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.  But without more details, it's still impossible to answer.